# The property 'isEmpty" can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add a validator to a widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app_1/utils/routes.dart';
    
    class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
    }
    
    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
      String name = "";
      bool changeButton = false;
    
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      moveToHome(BuildContext context) async {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          setState(() {
            changeButton = true;
          });
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
          await Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
          setState(() {
            changeButton = false;
          });
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/login_image.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 500,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Welcome $name",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 28.0,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter User Name",
                              labelText: "Username",
                            ),
                            validator: (String? value) {
                              if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
                                return "Username can't be empty";
                              }
    
                              return null;
                            },
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              name = value;
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter password",
                              labelText: "Password",
                            ),
                            validator: (String? value) {
                              if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
                                return "Password can't be empty";
                              }
    
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40.0,
                          ),
                          Material(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(changeButton ? 50 : 8),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () => moveToHome(context),
                              child: AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                width: changeButton ? 50 : 150,
                                height: 50,
                                //color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: changeButton
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.done,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                    : Text(
                                        "Login",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 18),
                                      ),
                                // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                //     //color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                //     // shape: changeButton
                                //     //     ? BoxShape.circle
                                //     //     : BoxShape.rectangle,
                                //     ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          // ElevatedButton(
                          //     child: Text("Login"),
                          //     style: TextButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: Size(150, 40)),
                          //     onPressed: () {
                          //       Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                          //     })
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

but I'm getting this error:

> The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

Answer (score 13):

You need to make the code null safe, to do that you have a few options, depending on what values you expect.

If you want a `String` value only then set the `initialValue` to `''` and update the validator condition to `(value!.isEmpty)` add an `!` after `value`.

If the value really can be null, then add a test to ensure that members are only accessed when the value isn’t null, that is if `initialValue` is set to `null`, then you would need to update validator to check for null.

```dart
validator: (String? value) {                        
  if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
    return "Username can't be empty";
  }

  return null;
}
```

If you want to know more about null-safety in dart check the [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety)

Answer (score 9):

The error you're facing came from null-safety, the value that you're getting from the validator method can be either null or either a String, so you may want to update your code to this example:

```dart
validator: (String? value) {                        
  if (value!.isEmpty) {
    return "Username cann't be empty";
  }

  return null;
}
```

You can learn more about null safety on official documentation:

https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

the correct if statement:

```
moveToHome(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        changeButton = true;
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.HomeRoute);
      setState(() {
        changeButton = false;
      });
```

form null safety issues:

```
TextFormField(
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Username", labelText: "Username"),

                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                        return "Username cannot be empty";
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      name = value;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),

                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Password", labelText: "Password"),

                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                        return "Password cannot be empty";
                      } else if (value!.length < 6) {
                        return "Password length should be atleast 6";
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
```