# The property 'quantity' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.')

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Relevent code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {}; // see that I have initialized the items
```

The code where I am getting the null safety error 'The property 'quantity' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').' The error I am getting is on the below *quantity* variable. I am not sure how to fix it. I have watched videos which talked about int?, ! and ?: operators but this particular scenario was not covered.

```
if (_items[productID].quantity == 1) _items.remove(productID);
```

Additional questions, what is the receiver here that the error is point to which can be null?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The property 'isEmpty" can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141719/the-property-isempty-cant-be-unconditionally-accessed-because-the-receiver-ca)

Comment: @IvánYoed yes this had to do with null safety which was introduced into flutter later. This is now resolved. Thx

Comment: I see! Thanks to you @Hammad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access a valid in a map, by passing a key to it.
If the id exist as a key in the map, then you will have a cartitem object indeed. But if the id does not exist, the result will be null, and your operation will become `null.quantity`.

The receiver here is your cartitem object.

Try:

```
_items[productID]!.quantity
```

This way, you promise dart that it's impossible to be null. Your error will go away, but this is a risky operation. The proper way to fix this, is make sure it's not null, before calling quantity on it.

Before your if statement, do this:

```
if (_items[productID] != null) if(_items[productID]!.quantity == 1) _items.remove(productID);
```

This way, you will for sure not make it into your second if statement, unless cartitem is not null, 100%.

Comment: As you can see in the code above, I have made them `required`, additionally if i try quanity = 0, in constructor, I get error. Not sure what to do

Comment: My bad, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's works for me.

```
if (_items[productID]?.quantity != 1)
```